# Are these database schemes correct?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I am making a polling system where each poll has multiple choices and a user can make multiple choices. And I would like to know if these schemes were correct

Namely:

- A guild cannot have two polls with the same id (Composite key)
- A poll cannot have multiple choices with the same id (Composite key)
- A user cannot make the same choice several times on a poll (Composite key)

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS guilds_polls
(
    guild_id BIGINT     NOT NULL,
    poll_id  varchar(8) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (guild_id, poll_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (guild_id) REFERENCES guilds (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS guilds_polls_choices
(
    guild_id  BIGINT       NOT NULL,
    poll_id   varchar(8)   NOT NULL,
    choice_id INT          NOT NULL,
    choice    VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (guild_id, poll_id, choice_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (guild_id, poll_id) REFERENCES guilds_polls (guild_id, poll_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS guilds_polls_user_choices
(
    guild_id  BIGINT     NOT NULL,
    poll_id   varchar(8) NOT NULL,
    choice_id BIGINT     NOT NULL,
    user_id   BIGINT     NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (guild_id, poll_id, user_id, choice_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (guild_id, poll_id) REFERENCES guilds_polls (guild_id, poll_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Answer (score 1):

LGTM.
But there is a small improvement we could make. Polls and choices is actually a n:n relation. That means multiple polls can have the same choice (A lot of polls are probably going to have the choices "no" and "yes") and one poll can have multiple choices (obviously). In your schema, you modeled it as a 1:n relation (every poll has multiple choices, but every choice has only one poll).

The solution would be to create a separate table Choices and then introduce a connecting table, which glues the choices to the polls. This way you have one table more, but a lot less duplicate data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS guilds_polls
(
    guild_id BIGINT     NOT NULL,
    poll_id  varchar(8) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (guild_id, poll_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (guild_id) REFERENCES guilds (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS guilds_polls_choices
(
    guild_id  BIGINT       NOT NULL,
    poll_id   varchar(8)   NOT NULL,
    choice_id INT          NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (guild_id, poll_id, choice_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (guild_id, poll_id) REFERENCES guilds_polls (guild_id, poll_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (choice_id) REFERENCES choices (choice_id) ON DELETE CASCADE

);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS choices
(
    choice_id INT          NOT NULL,
    choice    VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (choice_id),
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS guilds_polls_user_choices
(
    guild_id  BIGINT     NOT NULL,
    poll_id   varchar(8) NOT NULL,
    choice_id BIGINT     NOT NULL,
    user_id   BIGINT     NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (guild_id, poll_id, user_id, choice_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (guild_id, poll_id) REFERENCES guilds_polls (guild_id, poll_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    -- you also forgot this foreign key:
    FOREIGN KEY (choice_id) REFERENCES choices (choice_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

**Disclaimer**: not a PostgreSQL expert, so the syntax could be off.

Database modeling relies heavily on normalization (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Every database should follow the first 3 Normal Forms.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. A choice_id will have a value according to its index in the list of choices (e.g: 1, 2, 3), but with your solution, I could not have several times the same choice_id, right?

Comment: In that case I would add another column choice_index in the guilds_polls_choices table.

Comment: I could define the choice_id in autoincrement then?

Comment: Sure, choice_id can be anything... It just has to be unique (but that is assured by making it a primary key).

Comment: Okay great thanks so I applied what you suggested (https://pastebin.com/2fJJnAMH), and in my polling system for "No" and "Yes" I would put by default in `choices` the id = 0 for no and the id = 1 for yes

Comment: You could, yes. But like you said if you use Auto Increment, you let postgres handle that. Because it doesn't matter if "Yes" has the id 1 or the id 144356. The database access is not faster. Also you will always get the choice by joining and not by saving the choice_id somewhere (in the application).

Comment: It's not faster but it avoids more duplicate data, which avoids a hundred thousand "yes" votes, right?

Comment: No. You have to think that choice is connected to the choice_id. If "Yes" has the id 1550. Every poll with a "Yes" in it, will use the id 1550. There is no duplication. But it doesn't matter which id you use. What matters is that the combination of choice and choice_id has to be unique. (There should be no "YES" with id 1 and "YES" with id 2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248581/discussion-between-flavio-moreno-and-kaffarell).